# How to change cancel button title in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Currently I'm working on a multi-language application and I want to change the `Cancel` ,`Use` and `Retake` button titles of the `UIImagePickerController`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem is solved by using custom overlay class.

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add needed localizations in your project:
1) Select project file;
2) Select your project in "Project and Targets" list;
3) Select "Info" (in top part of screen);
4) Add needed languages in "Localizations" section.

Comment: The picker is embedded and in case the language setted without restarting the app, this way wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be automatically changed to device language.

You don't need o worry about this. Also you can't change it's behavior.

Controls like: `MFMessageComposer`, `MFMailComposer`, `UIImagePicker` etc. Will change it's default controls text to device language automatically.

Comment: if device language is English and i want to change the titles at that time how can we achieve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Assign delegate as self to your imagepicker controller and add the following code :

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

     UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@\"Done\"
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
   [bar setHidden:NO];
       ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
       ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @\"Pick Images\";
   ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only good solution is here...

```
//this is your camera method
- (void)startCameraControllerUsingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>)delegate gallery:(BOOL)openGallery
{
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil))
        return;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if (openGallery) {
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    } else {
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    //set your delegate type UINavigationControllerDelegate here! It will trigger function bellow!
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//UINavigationControllerDelegate function
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    //this is where magic happends! This leaves button empty and it will not ruin title center position!... or give it your desired string
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just find and change text of UIButton

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        for (UIView *v in viewController.view.subviews)
        {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"CMKBottomBar") class]])
            {
                SEL se = NSSelectorFromString(@"cancelButton");

                if ([v respondsToSelector:se])
                {
                    UIButton *cancelButton =  [v performSelector:se];
                    [cancelButton setTitle:@"New title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }

            }
        }
    }
```