# Change sizes of buttons in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a UIImagePickerController in my app to take video. My question is pretty straightforward: how can I make the buttons in the view larger, specifically the "use" button that appears after the video is done taking?

Comment: Try using a custom overlay class - [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436495/how-to-change-cancel-button-title-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom overlay to your UIImagePickerController. Then use custom buttons instead of the original ones.

Like so:

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    //hide old buttons
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    newButton.frame = CGRectMake(20,40,70,40);
    [overlay addSubview:newButton];

    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

You then add your new buttons to the overlay uiview.

As for the new buttons actions, you would need to look at the apple docs to see the methods for the original buttons. (like for taking a photo you would use - [picker takePicture];)

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, thanks! It seems like due to how complicated this sounds I probably won't bother since the button size thing wasn't a huge deal, but it's still good to know how to do this if I choose to.