# Change cancel button text in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem.
I want to translate the cancel button in a `UIImagePickerController`.
I tried different solutions but none of them worked.

Please find my actual code that works for changing title text but not for cancel button :

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {    
    imagePicker.navigationBar.topItem?.title = localizedString("ES_CUSTOMERS_EDIT_PHOTOS_TITLE")

    imagePicker.navigationBar.backItem?.title = localizedString("ES_CANCEL_BUTTON")
}
```

[Click here to see What i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp171.png)

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283220/2252297 it's in Objective-C if you need help with to translate it to swift let me know:)

Comment: See: [How do I localize UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258391/how-do-i-localize-uiimagepickercontroller) and [How to change cancel button title in UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436495/how-to-change-cancel-button-title-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Unless you want to show a different text it is not needed to translate it by yourself. If the user has the device in Spanish the button will show a message in Spanish.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.
I try all of them solutions but nothing change.
I update my post and added an image to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

         viewController.navigationItem.title = "your text..!!"    

    }
```

In Info.plist add (or change if already exists) the Localisations property array to the one you need (eg - Spanish or German or anything)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But it work just for title but i want to change the cancel button text.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the Cancel button using [UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/systemitem) of `cancel` (or Interface Builder), it will be localized for you automatically as others have mentioned.   If you're building the Cancel button yourself for some reason (not needed/recommended if the text is just 'Cancel'), use the appropriate constructor for UIBarButtonItem, for example based on your screenshot:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel the action"), style: .plain, target: <appropriate target here>)
```

If you're not sure how localization works in iOS, please see the Apple [Localizing Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1) documentation.